# Java2D Graphics anti-aliased

Tags: java, graphics, java-2d, antialiasing

I am new to Java and trying to use Java2D Graphics to create a Image. But the output is coming as anti-aliased. I tried many ways to rectify it but doesn't work. The characters are getting distorted or jagged.

```
public BufferedImage createNameOnButton(String label) {
    int messageWidth = 0;
    Font font = new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 11);

    BufferedImage bi = new BufferedImage(
        10, 10, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);

    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) bi.getGraphics();
    g2d.setRenderingHint(
        RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
        RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
    g2d.setRenderingHint(
        RenderingHints.KEY_TEXT_ANTIALIASING,
        RenderingHints.VALUE_TEXT_ANTIALIAS_ON);
    g2d.setRenderingHint(
        RenderingHints.KEY_FRACTIONALMETRICS,
        RenderingHints.VALUE_FRACTIONALMETRICS_ON);
    g2d.setFont(font);

    bi = g2d.getDeviceConfiguration()
        .createCompatibleImage(500, 30, Transparency.BITMASK);
    FontMetrics fm = bi.getGraphics().getFontMetrics(font);
    int messageHeight = fm.getHeight() - fm.getDescent();
    for (char ch : label.toCharArray()) {
        messageWidth += fm.charWidth(ch);
    }

    bi = bi.getSubimage(50, 0, messageWidth + 10, fm.getHeight());
    Graphics g = bi.getGraphics();
    g.setColor(Color.black);
    AttributedString as = new AttributedString(label);
    as.addAttribute(TextAttribute.FONT, font);
    g.drawString(as.getIterator(), 5, messageHeight);
    g2d.dispose();
    g.dispose();
    return bi;
}
```

Can anyone please help me to rectify the error?

Comment: What are you creating a 10x10 image first? Your code is really convoluted for what it is supposed to do.

Comment: I'm not completly sure I understand. From yor question, I understand you don't want the characters to be antialiased. But reading the code, it's no wonder, since it says ANTIALIAS_ON everywhere. Could you explain?

Comment: Thanks for stating that - I tested the code with ANTIALIAS_OFF but there are some characters that still comes as anti-aliased (not all characters) like, the vertical '\' of N, 'a', 'v', 'e', y' , 'o' - basically the edges of characters are not smooth. Is there anything else I have do?

Comment: Also as mentioned below - My requirement is to write a function that returns a BufferedImage that contains a text of pattern "Deliver Me to <User address>". The phrase "Deliver Me to" should be in black color while "<User Address>" which is collected within the flow should be in blue color. Can you please provide some inputs on the same?

Answer (score 12):

Assuming you actually want smooth (non-aliased) text, [`TextLayout`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/font/TextLayout.html) may make this easier. The [`FontRenderContext`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/font/FontRenderContext.html) constructor can manage the anti-aliasing and fractional metrics settings.

Addendum: Using `g2d.setColor(Color.blue)` seems to produce the expected effect.

Addendum: On Mac OS X, the `Pixie` application in `/Developer/Applications/Graphics Tools/` is convenient for examining the anti-alias pixels. On other platforms, [`Zoom`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3742841) may be used.

[image]

```
/** @see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4285464 */
public class BITest extends JPanel {

    private BufferedImage image = createNameOnButton("Sample");

    public BITest() {
        this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(
            image.getWidth(), image.getHeight()));
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);
    }

    public BufferedImage createNameOnButton(String label) {
        Font font = new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 64);
        FontRenderContext frc = new FontRenderContext(null, true, true);
        TextLayout layout = new TextLayout(label, font, frc);
        Rectangle r = layout.getPixelBounds(null, 0, 0);
        System.out.println(r);
        BufferedImage bi = new BufferedImage(
            r.width + 1, r.height + 1,
            BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) bi.getGraphics();
        g2d.setColor(Color.blue);
        layout.draw(g2d, 0, -r.y);
        g2d.dispose();
        return bi;
    }

    private void display() {
        JFrame f = new JFrame("BITest");
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.setUndecorated(true);
        f.add(this);
        f.pack();
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                new BITest().display();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the sample program. My requirement is to write a function that returns a BufferedImage that contains a text of pattern "Deliver Me to <User address>". The phrase "Deliver Me to" should be in black color while "<User Address>" which is collected within the flow should be in blue color. 

Can you please provide some inputs on the same?

Comment: Also forgot to add that since it has to be placed on a button, image size has to be of specific width and height. I tried the sample program but the image rendered is completely black and was not able to see the text written.

Please note that I am completely new in Java.

Comment: Just to add - I got the image but actually I need to store and view the same as within a file. So how can I write the what is displayed via display() method to a file.

Comment: @Prakash: I'd use `ImageIO.write()` to save the `BufferedImage`. You can call `setColor()` as needed for each line.

Comment: Thanks, but the setColor() method is setting the full image as green not the text color. I need to print the text in Black color and background as white / grey.

Comment: One thing please note that for output I cannot use JFrame or make use of display() method

Comment: Since the image should be accessible via a URL JFrame or any application window cannot be used to render

Comment: public BufferedImage createNameOnButton(String label, String decorateText){ Font font = new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 11); FontRenderContext frc = new FontRenderContext(null, true, true); TextLayout layout = new TextLayout(label, font, frc); Rectangle r = layout.getPixelBounds(null, 0, 0); bi = new BufferedImage(r.width + 5, r.height, Transparency.BITMASK); Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) bi.getGraphics(); g2d.setColor(Color.black); layout.draw(g2d, 0, -r.y); g2d.drawImage(bi, 0, 0, null); g2d.dispose(); return bi;} The image produced is black. Setting Text color/background no luck.

Comment: @Prakash:`Transparency.BITMASK` is a valid `BufferedImage` type, but only by coincidence. There's no need to copy the image onto itself with `g2d.drawImage(bi, 0, 0, null)`.

Comment: I tried removing the option [copying the image to itself] but still the result is not achieved.

Comment: @Prakash: I updated my example, and `setColor()` appears to change the text color. I don't see where your code is going wrong. Please edit your question, as code in comments is almost unreadable.

Comment: I was unable to edit the code and started a new thread related to same issue - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4316815/java2d-graphics-anti-aliased . Please have a look at the detailed description there and provide required resolution. As mentioned please read thru the descriptive and provide solutions.

Answer (score 6):

As Traroth mentioned it is more than likely due to

```
g2d.setRenderingHint(
    RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
    RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
g2d.setRenderingHint(
    RenderingHints.KEY_TEXT_ANTIALIASING,
    RenderingHints.VALUE_TEXT_ANTIALIAS_ON);
```

Instead this should be

```
g2d.setRenderingHint(
    RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
    RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_OFF);
g2d.setRenderingHint(
    RenderingHints.KEY_TEXT_ANTIALIASING,
    RenderingHints.VALUE_TEXT_ANTIALIAS_OFF);
```

Comment: Thanks for stating that - I tested the code with ANTIALIAS_OFF but there are some characters that still comes as anti-aliased (not all characters) like, the vertical '\' of N, 'a', 'v', 'e'' y' , 'o' - basically the edges of characters are not smooth. Is there anything else I have do?

Comment: You seem not to understand what anti-aliasing means. Anti-aliased=smooth.

Answer (score 2):

I found that just [this line](http://tinybrain.de/1006843) does the trick:

```
  g.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_TEXT_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_TEXT_ANTIALIAS_ON);
```

After that, just use [drawString()](http://tinybrain.de/1006841).