# How can I align text with a Graphics2D without appeal?

Tags: java, graphics, text, drawing

The function drawString(...) does not have anything similar "anchor" that I could put the x and y in the center of the text. I know I can do it manually, and I don't want to use JTextArea or JLabels as well. Is it possible to do it in a smart way or has no way to do that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`TextLayout`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/font/TextLayout.html) offers a few conveniences. Here's an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4287269).

Answer (score 4):

From the Graphics object get the `FontMetrics()`, and and use `getStringBounds()` to get the image size of your text. From that you can figure out what the x and y should be to position the text whereever you want.

Comment: This is the not-so-smart way, or, as I said, "manually". It is appeal! :) But it's OK, I think definitely it is the only not-so-bad solution. Thanks anyway!

Comment: @Felipe Micaroni Lalli "This is the not-so-smart way, or, as I said, "manually"." <dws>Yes it is a sad fact that sometimes programmers actually need to program, rather than simply call the voodoo API.</dws>

Comment: @Andrew +1 :)
Though I remember when I was programming GUI in C under MSDOS, it was possible to specify if the given coordinates were centered or left/right aligned in X/Y directions. I guess Java had us used to be lazy somehow :)