# how to create anti-aliased text images in java

Tags: java, image

Is there a standard way of creating images (PNGs preferably) in Java that antialiases the text properly?

I'd like to avoid iText due to licensing issues, although this is for an open source project.

Comment: See also [Java2D Graphics Anti-Aliased Text](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4285464/java2d-graphics-anti-aliased/4287269#4287269)

Answer (score 1):

[Batik](http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/batik/) can do this.