# Java Write Text Image with Specific Fonts

Tags: java, graphics, graphics2d, antialiasing

I'm writing some text on top of an existing image and the font isn't very sharp.  Is there some settings either with the Graphics2D or Font classes that help make fonts look nicer when writing text on top of images?  The Dante font doesn't come out as Dante when I write it. I've tried to use antialiasing but it had no effect (see setRenderingHint).  The images came out the same with or without the RenderingHint set.  Any suggestions?

```
public class ImageCreator{

public void createImage(String text){
     Graphics2D g = img.createGraphics(); //img is a BufferedImage read in from file system
     g.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
                    RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
     Font fnt=new Font("Dante",1,20);
     Color fntC = new Color(4, 4, 109);       
     g.setColor(fntC);
     g.setFont(fnt);
     Dimension d = new Dimension(200, 113);
     drawCenteredString(text, d.width, d.height, g);
}
public static void drawCenteredString(String s, int w, int h, Graphics g) {
      FontMetrics fm = g.getFontMetrics();
      int x = (w - fm.stringWidth(s)) / 2;
      int y = (fm.getAscent() + (h - (fm.getAscent() + fm.getDescent())) / 2);
      g.drawString(s, x, y);
}

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`TextLayout`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/font/TextLayout.html), as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4285464/java2d-graphics-anti-aliased/4287269#4287269).

Addendum: The advantage of [`TextLayout`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/font/TextLayout.html) is that `RenderingHints` may be applied to the `FontRenderContext`.

Comment: Thanks for the response trashgod, but that actually made it look worse

Comment: That's disappointing. What result did you get form the example I cited? Did you apply your `RenderingHints` to the `FontRenderContext` of the `TextLayout`? Can you update you question with the new code?

Comment: the problem was the font was not available on the JVM.

Comment: Interesting. Was the system substituting a different font, presumably with different metrics?