# Appending Text On Images

Tags: java, image, image-processing

I am having a background image and I want to append text on a specific area of an image using Java.Is that possible? I want to do this for batch.

Can any one suggest me, how can I do that?

Are there any tools where I can append text on images?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Using Graphics2D to overlay text on a BufferedImage and return a BufferedImage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2658554/using-graphics2d-to-overlay-text-on-a-bufferedimage-and-return-a-bufferedimage/2658663#2658663)

[Java Write Text Image with Specific Fonts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5878517/java-write-text-image-with-specific-fonts)

http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.3/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html#drawString(java.text.AttributedCharacterIterator,int,int)

Answer (score 0):

There is **drawString()** method in **Graphics2D** object. You can obtain Graphics from existing Image and then draw there your String.