# Specify line spacing while appending text on Image

Tags: java, image, awt, java-2d

I am [Appending Text on images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8223640/appending-text-on-images). How to specify the Line spacing between two lines while appending on the text on the image?

**EDIT:-** I want to Control Line Height of the text.

```
final BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(new File(Background));
Graphics g = image.getGraphics();
java.awt.Font a=new java.awt.Font("AndaleWTJ", java.awt.Font.PLAIN, 26);
g.setFont(a);
g.setColor(Color.RED);
FontMetrics fm = g.getFontMetrics();
drawString(g,Title,15, 84,402,199,171,1);
g.dispose();

public static void drawString(Graphics g, String s, int x, int y, int width,int red_val,int green_val, int blue_val)
{     FontMetrics fm = g.getFontMetrics();
      java.awt.Color c= new java.awt.Color(red_val, green_val, blue_val);
      g.setColor(c);
      int lineHeight = fm.getHeight();
      int curX = x;
      int curY = y;
  String[] words = s.split(" ");
        for (String word : words)
        {
                // Find out thw width of the word.
                int wordWidth = fm.stringWidth(word + " ");

                // If text exceeds the width, then move to next line.
                if (curX + wordWidth >= x + width)
                {
                        curY += lineHeight;
                        curX = x;
                }
                g.drawString(word, curX, curY);
                // Move over to the right for next word.
                curX += wordWidth;
        }
}
```

Comment: ..use a bigger `y` offset for `drawString(..)`.  If that does not answer the question, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: Post the code you are using to output the lines on your image now. It is easier to comment on how to fix it than explaining it without an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now I am Passing value for lineHeight instead of  **int lineHeight = fm.getHeight();**

```
 public static void drawString(Graphics g, String s, int x, int y, int width,int red_val,int green_val, int blue_val, int lineHeight )
    {     FontMetrics fm = g.getFontMetrics();
          java.awt.Color c= new java.awt.Color(red_val, green_val, blue_val);
          g.setColor(c);
          int curX = x;
          int curY = y;
      String[] words = s.split(" ");
            for (String word : words)
            {
                    // Find out thw width of the word.
                    int wordWidth = fm.stringWidth(word + " ");

                    // If text exceeds the width, then move to next line.
                    if (curX + wordWidth >= x + width)
                    {
                            curY += lineHeight;
                            curX = x;
                    }
                    g.drawString(word, curX, curY);
                    // Move over to the right for next word.
                    curX += wordWidth;
            }
    }
```

Comment: Is this supposed to be an answer, or an expansion of the question?  If it is not an answer, please edit it into the question.

Comment: @AndrewThompson :- This is answer. Now I can adjust lineHeight as  per my requirement. Thanks for your valuable feedback

Answer (score 1):

If a bigger y as @Andrew Thompson post in comment isn't enough flexible for you. This is what you are looking for http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/text/drawmulstring.html