# Display SplashScreen using Timer

Tags: java

I want to show a splashScreen on my app firstly for few seconds and then load all my threads data using timer in java, then how should i do it.

Comment: in main method, you need to create a borderless JFrame, that shows your splash screen, then sleep for some second and rest of the work

Comment: Use the `SplashScreen` class as discussed [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6401999/418556).

Answer (score 0):

Add Splash Screen Activity to your Project...
now replace the SplashScree.java file code as :

```
    package samples.splash.screen;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.os.Handler;

    /**
     * Splash screen activity
     *
     * @author Catalin Prata
     */
    public class SplashScreen extends Activity {

        // used to know if the back button was pressed in the splash screen activity and avoid opening the next activity
        private boolean mIsBackButtonPressed;
        private static final int SPLASH_DURATION = 2000; // 2 seconds


        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            setContentView(R.layout.splash_screen);

            Handler handler = new Handler();

            // run a thread after 2 seconds to start the home screen
            handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {

                    // make sure we close the splash screen so the user won't come back when it presses back key

                    finish();

                    if (!mIsBackButtonPressed) {
                        // start the home screen if the back button wasn't pressed already 
                        Intent intent = new Intent(SplashScreen.this, Home.class);
                        SplashScreen.this.startActivity(intent);
                   }

                }

            }, SPLASH_DURATION); // time in milliseconds (1 second = 1000 milliseconds) until the run() method will be called

        }

        @Override
       public void onBackPressed() {

            // set the flag to true so the next activity won't start up
            mIsBackButtonPressed = true;
            super.onBackPressed();

        }

}
```

And the splash_screen xml looks like this: where you should have any image in your drawables named : "splash_screen"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent"
              android:background="@drawable/splash_screen"/>
```

Now make your Splash Screen a Launcher Activity in Manifest File to make it a startup Activity..
And in order to get the title bar of the application down, just add he activity in your manifest and add the theme as you can see below:

```
<activity android:name=".SplashScreen" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN">
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER">
            </category></action></intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

Comment: Who said this was for Android?

Answer (score 0):

Visit the following excellent tutorial on splash screen in Java(Swing).

[Adding a splash screen to your application](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=4&cad=rja&ved=0CDwQFjAD&url=http://forum.codecall.net/topic/56841-adding-a-splash-screen-to-your-swing-application/&ei=H2zZUeaVD47xrQf8m4HYDA&usg=AFQjCNFL113fAT84tIGyUWfT3jWv3IPWCA&bvm=bv.48705608,d.bmk)