# How can I make my JLabel's text, using a custom font, antialiased?

Tags: java, swing, fonts, antialiasing

I'm trying to create a SWING application using Java 1.6 and I have a JLabel that uses a custom font from a .ttf file.

I thought 1.6 had anti-aliasing on by default, but my text is pretty pixelized.

Here's a code sample and an image showing the result:

```
package aceprobowler.test;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.io.InputStream;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

import aceprobowler.options.OptionsValues;

public class TestAntialiasedText extends JFrame
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 2411330284507353990L;

    public TestAntialiasedText(String title)
    {
        super(title);
        setSize(800,200);
        
        Font titleFont = null;
        
        try
        {
            InputStream is = OptionsValues.class.getResourceAsStream("fonts//KOMIKAX_.ttf");
            titleFont = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, is).deriveFont(Font.PLAIN, 60);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            System.err.println("font not loaded.  Using serif font.");
            titleFont = new Font("serif", Font.PLAIN, 24);
        }
        
        JPanel panelWithText = new JPanel();
        JLabel labelWithText = new JLabel("This is a test");
        
        labelWithText.setFont(titleFont);
        
        labelWithText.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        labelWithText.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        labelWithText.setOpaque(true);
        
        panelWithText.add(labelWithText);
        add(panelWithText);
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                new TestAntialiasedText("Testing text anti-alias").setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Mostly apparent on the "T"s and on the "A"
[image: Not anti-aliased text]

I tried creating an inner class overriding paintComponent(Graphics g) and using

```
Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g; 
g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON)
```

But it doesn't work. Can anyone help me out with this? I can't find any information on the internet about this since Javaj 1.6 is supposed to make everything SWING related Anti-aliased by default.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you override the `paintComponent` method of the `JLabel` instance, I believe that you'll need to use the following:

- [`Graphics.drawString(String str, int x, int y)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html#drawString%28java.lang.String,%20int,%20int%29)
- [`RenderingHints.KEY_TEXT_ANTIALIASING`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/RenderingHints.html#KEY_TEXT_ANTIALIASING)

For an example, see:

- [RichJLabel](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-Components/LabelwithlargefontandANTIALIASpaint.htm)

Comment: @Adam Smith, Odd. I haven't tested this myself. I am assuming your implementation closely resembles the `RichJLabel` example I linked you?

Comment: Sorry about last comment, I had typed something wrong in the paintComponent method, it works now! It makes it a bit more complicated than just typing the text in the constructor, but at least it works... Thanks a lot, I really appreciate your help! Just a question, though: Since the x,y coordinates are the baseline of the left-most letter, is there a way to calculate those coordinates easily to make the text appear at the same spot as it normally would if I hadn't overriden paintComponent?

Comment: @Adam Smith. No problem. And good question. That's something I'll have to think about some more. Busy at the moment! Thanks for the questions and replies. :D

Answer (score 3):

I believe that the default for font anti-aliasing varies by platform. You don't say what platform you are on. In any case, setting the text antialiasing rendering hint should fix it.

Comment: I'm using Windows Vista. Setting the rendering hints with the text antialising settings didn't work, though.

Answer (score 3):

Another approach is to use [`TextLayout`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/font/TextLayout.html) and supply a [`FontRenderContext`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/font/FontRenderContext.html) that `isAntiAliased`, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4285464/java2d-graphics-anti-aliased/4287269#4287269).

Comment: just question, because this topic isn't my cup of Java, aren't possible/safiest that with `setFont(myFont)` (for plain Text) by using `myLabel.setText(someString)`, or in special cases `myLabel.setText(htmlformatter)` +1

Comment: I'd have to agree: simpler is probably better, although I like `TextLayout` when I need the best metrics, e.g. composite controls.