# How do we do text measurements without a prior call to paintComponent?

Tags: java, swing, graphics, text, measurement

Hi all I need to do some text measuring using [`java.awt.font.FontRenderContext`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/font/FontRenderContext.html), however this class requires me to supply a graphics object.

From what I know, the only way I could grab a graphics object is through the paintComponent / paint methods:

```
@Override public void paintComponent(java.awt.Graphics g){ //...
```

However I need to do this measurement even before the `paintComponent` method is called. I was wondering what's the best solution to this problem?

Do I create a dummy JLabel to do the job?

Comment: +1 for using a) Using `FontRenderContext` rather than `FontMetrics`. b) Linking to the docs. c) Linking to the v. 7 docs.

Comment: Whats wrong with FontMetrics?

Comment: Nothing's wrong with [`FontMetrics`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/FontMetrics.html), but it's abstract; it has to be examined in some context, e.g. a `FontRenderContext` in a `Graphics2D` context.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No need to create dummy GUI components. You could for instance create a `BufferedImage`

```
Graphics g = new BufferedImage(1, 1, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB).getGraphics();
```

Comment: Btw I was wondering is this the very thing "A FontRenderContext which is directly constructed will most likely not represent any actual graphics device, and may lead to unexpected or incorrect results." http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/font/FontRenderContext.html tells us not to do ?

Comment: But the sentence right in front of it explains that it's ok if it's obtained from a graphics object. (Because then the FontRenderContext is not created out of thin air... it has been carefully constructed by the Graphics object.)

Comment: `BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB`  Why the (upper case) `A`?  It seems unnecessary.

Comment: @AndrewThompson do you mean we should use `BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB` ?

Comment: @Pacerier Answer me this.  What is the advantage of the BI to which we are not going to write, supporting transparency?

Comment: @AndrewThompson do you mean i can any one of them? including `BufferedImage.TYPE_CUSTOM` as well?

Comment: [BufferedImage.TYPE_CUSTOM](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html#TYPE_CUSTOM) *"This type is only used as a return value for the getType() method."*  What happened when *you* tried it?

Comment: @AndrewThompson I had an exception because the size is (0,0). I changed it to (1,1) and had an exception beacuse of `TYPE_CUSTOM`. Btw `TYPE_BYTE_BINARY` seems to work, do you know if there's any difference using RGB / GRAY / BINARY etc ?

Comment: I typically just use `INT_RGB`.  For this use, I guess any of the rest would be sufficient.

Comment: Updated answer according to your find @Pacerier.

Comment: I'm a bit puzzled by this answer.  I just tried it before making my JFrame visible and the Graphics I got, to my non-surprise, gave me the wrong answer for a FontMetrics.stringWidth(...).  I stipulate that I had previously swapped all fonts in UIManager for slightly larger derived versions of themselves.  But the answer I got, as I'd expect, gave the true pixel width figure for the original versions.  I **think** that it is only when components go visible that you can get an accurate Graphics...

Comment: ... I then applied the magnification factor used to derive the substitute UIManager fonts to the stringWidth figure (for "Hello World"): 96 pixels.  The true figure, using the realised derived font once things are visible is 93 pixels.  A useful guide for certain purposes but doesn't give what the OP wants.

Answer (score 4):

> However I need to do this measurement even before the paintComponent method is called

You should probably be overriding the getPreferredSize() method of the component. This is how Swing components know how to size and layout components before they are visible.

A JLabel uses the following:

```
FontMetrics fm = getFontMetrics(getFont());
```

Or if you need the FontRenderContext() then you can probably use the `getGraphics()` method of the object. Normally I recommend not to use this method, but that is because people then try to do custom painting with the Graphics object. However in this case you just want the Graphics object to measure the text so it should be ok.

Comment: Ic, so `getGraphics` is for that kind of purpose isn't it?

Comment: blimey, pretty bold stuff... overriding preferredSize() I mean.  One thought that occurs to me: what do you then do with this information, since preferredSize is only going to be called during realisation?  I suggest this is no better than adjusting your component sizes after realisation, but undesirable because dangerous practice.  Please give me your view of my thoughts on aioobe's suggestion if you have a mo.

Comment: @mikerodent,  I don't have any thoughts on aioobe's suggestion because I don't understand it or the requirement of the question. Questions like this usually result when the poster doesn't understand how Swing works. The question doesn't give a concrete reason (or example) why then OP thinks they need the size before paintComponent() is called. My suggestion was to override the getPreferredSize() method because that is what Swing components do. I don't see the reason for not following this approach.

Comment: Thanks. In my use case, which led me here, I want to create a table where a column is just the right width from the start to accommodate a rendered date: rendering obviously depending on the date format but also the font.  I think doing this just after "setVisible" should be fine... but there appear to be a couple of ways of doing it before...

Comment: @mikerodent, `I want to create a table where a column is just the right width from the start to accommodate a rendered date` - see [Table Column Adjuster](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/10/table-column-adjuster/).

Answer (score 3):

[`TextLayout`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/font/TextLayout.html) may be useful in this context. This [example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5998117/230513) compares the result with that obtained from a text component's `FontMetrics`, and this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4287269/230513) expands on @aioobe's `BufferedImage` suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

Or you could do this in your component constructor

```
Font font = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, new File("ARIAL.TTF"));
font = font.deriveFont(12f);
FontMetrics fontMetrics = getFontMetrics(font);
```

Comment: nice.  Or just FontMetrics fontMetrics = getFontMetrics( getFont() )... i.e. to use the font of the component.

Answer (score 0):

Following on from aioobe's answer, it's a clever way of getting a Graphics.  Maybe everyone realises this, but a Graphics object comes with a particular font, which with aioobe's generic way of getting a Graphics could be anything.

I had to do this (Jython):

```
g = java.awt.image.BufferedImage(1, 1, java.awt.image.BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB).graphics
g.font = my_table.font
```

After that, this gives an accurate figure, before anything has been realised... hurrah:

```
hw_width = g.fontMetrics.stringWidth( "Hello World" )
```