# Display text in Swing without JLabel

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I have to make a Java Program using Swing and I want to show some text, but not using `JLabel` (including text component)! I have to extends `JFrame`. What other options do I have?

Comment: That's a rather strange restriction. Do you have any other restrictions we should know about before suggesting answers? Why can you not use a JLabel?

Comment: I don't think this question is too localized—there may be a reason to render text directly—but more context would help.

Comment: Other restrictions could be  if the text must wrap the words before show.

Comment: Dont rewrite/delete question text with nonsense, either delete it, leave it for now and come back later when you know exactly or mark as solved if it is. But editing a question to now say: *I have to think about it more...* is not good idea it will be removed.

Answer (score 4):

You should not:

- Extend `JFrame` unnecessarily
- Draw directly to `JFrame` via `paint(..)`

You should:

- override `JComponent`s `paintComponent(...)`
- do custom painting in `paintComponent(...)`,
- add `JComponent` instance to `JFrame`

Here is an example for you:

[image]

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.FontMetrics;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class DrawSimpleText {

    public DrawSimpleText() {
        initComponents();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new DrawSimpleText();
            }
        });
    }

    private void initComponents() {
        JFrame f = new JFrame();
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.getContentPane().add(new JPanel(true) {
            Font font = new Font("Serif", Font.PLAIN, 20);
            String s = "Java Source and Support";

            @Override
            public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
                super.paintComponent(g);
                Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;

                g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
                        RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
                g2.setFont(font);

                FontMetrics fm = g.getFontMetrics(font);

                int width = fm.stringWidth(s);

                Dimension d = getSize();

                //center String/text
                int cx = (d.width - width) / 2;
                int cy = (d.height - fm.getHeight()) / 2 + fm.getAscent();

                g2.drawString(s, cx, cy);
            }

            @Override
            public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
                return new Dimension(300, 100);
            }
        });
        f.pack();
        f.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

**UPDATE:**

As per your comment **though its going against all Swing rules and my own morals**:

However if you still **need** to do this (which I cannot fathom why this is just bad practice) here is how:

[image]

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.FontMetrics;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class DrawSimpleText extends JFrame {

    public DrawSimpleText() {
        initComponents();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new DrawSimpleText();
            }
        });
    }

    private void initComponents() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        pack();
        setVisible(true);
    }
    Font font = new Font("Serif", Font.PLAIN, 20);
    String s = "Java Source and Support";

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {

        super.paint(g);
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;

        g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
                RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        g2.setFont(font);

        FontMetrics fm = g.getFontMetrics(font);

        int width = fm.stringWidth(s);

        Dimension d = getSize();

        //center String/text
        int cx = (d.width - width) / 2;
        int cy = (d.height - fm.getHeight()) / 2 + fm.getAscent();

        g2.drawString(s, cx, cy);
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(300, 100);
    }
}
```

Comment: not extends JPlanel but extends JFrame, Is it working?

Comment: Also consider `TextLayout` for better metrics, as shown [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4287269/230513).

Comment: @user1769093 that is not considered good practice, but see my updated post

Comment: @trashgod +1 yup even better :)

Comment: Why the values are hardcoded? And also how about double buffer?

Comment: @RomanC +1 yes good one added double buffer. What hard coded values the text co-ordinates?

Comment: yes it's hardcoded i.e. cannot change by the API.

Comment: @RomanC while I'm all for flexible APIs, this is just an example & demonstrates the basic requirements of the OP. +1

Comment: @trashgod added FontMetrics :)

Comment: @RomanC added `FontMetrics` so values not hard coded

Comment: @MadProgrammer Showing a bad practices in the example doesn't fill the requirements of the OP.

Comment: @MadProgrammer +1 yup I do agree, although we should give good examples whats the use of giving an example that is near perfect OP wont learn...

Comment: @david teach em to fish, sometimes pointing them in the right direction is more important then giving then the right answer

Comment: @romanc I don't think this is a bad example. There are no requirements from the OP with regards to layout, they wanted to draw text. If we start second guessing the requirements we could not only be wasting our time but also introducing irrelevancy into the answer. I agree, we should correct bad practice when we see it and encourage good practice, but there's only so much we can guess at. I don't think in this case going all out with providing properties to set the text position is required to answer the OPs question ... IMHO