# How to write text inside a rectangle

Tags: java, arrays, swing, jpanel, paintcomponent

Hi I am creating a java  desktop application where I am drawing rectangle. I want to write some text inside rectangle.

How can I achieve this?

Here is my code:

```
class DrawPanel extends JPanel {

    private void doDrawing(Graphics g) {
        int a=90;
        int b=60;
        int c=10;
        int d=15;


        ArrayList<Graphics2D> g1 = new ArrayList<Graphics2D>();
        for(int i=0;i<=9;i++){

        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;

        g2d.setColor(new Color(212, 212, 212));
        g2d.drawRect(c, d, a, b);



        d+=65;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

        super.paintComponent(g);
        doDrawing(g);
    }
}
```

Comment: everything inside doDrawing about Graphics2D shoould be in paintComponent, in doDrawing to create only coordinates, Objects, inside paintComponent only to loop inside arrray of prepared Objects

Comment: Use [`drawString`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html#drawString(java.lang.String,int,int)) method. after `drawRect`.

Comment: Also consider `TextLayout`, seen [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4287269/230513).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use your `Graphics2D` object and call `drawString(String str, int x, int y)`. Something like

```
 g2d.drawRect(c, d, a, b);
 g2d.drawString("Hi", (a+c)/2, (b+d)/2);
```

Note that the Javadoc specifies

> Draws the text given by the specified string, using this graphics context's current font and color. The baseline of the leftmost character is at position (x, y) in this graphics context's coordinate system.

so you would need to take into account the space the font takes on screen. Use [`FontMetrics`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/FontMetrics.html) for that.

Comment: It's the a and c you defined, it's just an example, I don't know if that's where you want your String.

Comment: y parameter of drawString sets the baseline of the string, (b+d)/2 will align the string baseline to the center vertically, not the text itself.

Comment: @GeeBee Where in the question or the answer does it say anything about setting the string to the center? I even said in the comment above yours that I don't know where OP wanted the string. That's no reason to downvote.

Comment: @user1803551 you are right, I missed the point that centering was not requested. 

It still worth to mention that the y coordinate in drawString sets the _baseline_ of the text, instead of the top-left corner (as in other drawing operations such as drawRect). You need to add the ascent of the font (from the fontmetrics - then linemetrics structures) if you wish to have the text really rendered inside the rectangle (and not partially above or over the top line).

Comment: @GeeBee Added the info.

Comment: Great! :) sorry for the confusion.