# Can't get JFrame to refresh image

Tags: java, image, swing, applet, jframe

Hey, so I'm working on a program and for debugging purposes, I'm trying to get the program to take a screenshot of a part of the display. I want to have the display updated, but I can't seem to get it to work. I'm sure it's a simple issue, but my experience with Java Applets is very small.

Here's the part that I'm having issues with:

```
...
Thread.sleep(5000);
    try {gb = new GameBoard(frame.getBounds());}
    catch(Exception e){System.out.println("Error.");} // Make "gameboard" Object

    while (true)
    {
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        gb.grabImage(); // use java.awt.Robot's createScreenCapture()

        ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(gb.image()); // wrap the image 
        JLabel label = new JLabel(icon, JLabel.CENTER);
        frame.getContentPane().add(label,BorderLayout.EAST); //display the image (works)
        //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, label, "icon", -1);
        label.repaint(); //update the display??
        frame.repaint();
        frame.getContentPane().repaint();
    }
```

As I said, the image appears, and will create new ones if I change the Applet size, but I need a constantly changing image.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you sure this is an applet and not an application?  I believe default settings prohibit the creation of java.awt.Robot in an applet.

Comment: Try doing this...`label.revalidate(); label.repaint();`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are creating and adding a new `JLabel` each time through the loop. Because you are changing the structure of the component tree you'll need to call `revalidate` on the frame's content pane.

A better solution would be to just change the image on a single JLabel. Create one label, add it, then in your loop use `JLabel.setIcon` and `repaint`.

Comment: By the way, you should read up on how to use Swing with threads - you should make all your GUI changes on the event dispatch thread by using `SwingUtilities.invokeLater` and `SwingUtilities.invokeAndwait`. Swing components are not thread-safe so changing the component tree or calling setters on Swing components can be unsafe if done from other threads.

Answer (score 2):

As @RD notes, [`createScreenCapture()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html#createScreenCapture%28java.awt.Rectangle%29) will throw a `SecurityException` if the applet is not signed. Sleeping on the event dispatch thread may be blocking updates. This [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3742841) captures a screen image as the mouse is dragged; its `BufferedImage` "remembers" the last image captured.

Comment: Minor quibble:  The applet will throw a SecurityException if it is not trusted.  This requires that it both be signed, and when the time comes, the user is both able to, and decides to, accept the signed code.  This is a subtle but important distinction since for example, the JCP can be configured so that users are able to accept code signed by a verified security certificate, but not if it was one generated purely by the developer.

Comment: @Andrew Thompson: Thanks for expanding on this!

Answer (score 0):

From what I remember, `repaint()` in Java should really have been called `invalidate()` -- it doesn't actually repaint the window; it only invalidates it so it can be repainted by the OS at the next opportunity. I didn't look carefully at your code, but I think this might be the issue. I'm not sure how to force a redraw, but an idea would be to return from the function, then have a timer interrupt you and paint it then -- that way, the OS will have a chance to paint the window.

Comment: Not quite. `repaint` marks the component as needing to be painted; `invalidate` marks the component as needing to have its layout recalculated. There is a `repaintImmediately` method if you **really** want it to repaint right now, but you don't want to use that unless you're absolutely sure about what you're doing.

Comment: I didn't know there was an `invalidate` method in Java -- I was referring to `invalidate` as used in Windows (like `InvalidateRect()`) and the .NET Framework (like `Control.Invalidate()`), as that refers to painting and not layout. Thanks for pointing it out though, sorry for the confusin.