# Java get color of pixel LIVE

Tags: java, colors, mouse

I have a problem with finding the current color under the cursor.

My code:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.MouseInfo;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.PointerInfo;
import java.awt.Robot;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        PointerInfo pointer;
        pointer = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo();
        Point coord = pointer.getLocation();

        Robot robot = new Robot();
        robot.delay(2000);

        while(true) {
            coord = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation();       
            Color color = robot.getPixelColor((int)coord.getX(), (int)coord.getX());
            if(color.getGreen() == 255 && color.getBlue() == 255 && color.getRed() == 255) {
                System.out.println("WHITE FOUND");
            }
            robot.delay(1000);
        }
    }
}
```

When I run it, even when I hold my mouse on the gray area, I am getting “WHITE FOUND WHITE FOUND” message.

What can be the problem? Can you guys test if it does not work for you also?

Added Picture: I am holding my cursor on Eclipse gray area but getting “WHITE FOUND” message.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the problem is you are using getX twice instead of getX and getY

```
Color color = robot.getPixelColor((int)coord.getX(), (int)coord.getX())
```

Should be

```
Color color = robot.getPixelColor((int)coord.getX(), (int)coord.getY())
```

Answer (score 2):

You're using getX() twice. [min length]

Answer (score 0):

You might also like [`Zoom`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3742731/java-how-to-draw-constantly-changing-graphics/3742841#3742841), which uses the related method [`createScreenCapture()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html#createScreenCapture%28java.awt.Rectangle%29) to collect screen pixels *en masse* and display color information about each in a tool tip.