# How to get a pixel color in Java

Tags: java

The Robot getPixelColor method always returns the color of chosen pixel from the desktop screen. I would like to get the color of the pixel that we see in real time.

Is that possible?

Comment: Possible duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7168839/how-does-robots-getpixelcolorint-x-int-y-method-work

Comment: Just to point this out, perception of color is relative. Color blindness, mutations, etc.

Comment: Have a thread pool `Robot`...?

Comment: The computer doesn't know anything more than the color of the pixel. That's all it's doing. The color you see is the color your eye interperets, which you can't really get without either some sort of probe in your eye or a really really good model of your eye. Color of the pixel is the best you can do.