# Java getting area of pixels and turning into an image - how can this be made more efficient?

Tags: java, swing, awt, sun

I have some code which will grab an area of pixels on the screen and turn them into a BufferedImage object. The thing is - it is MASSIVELY slow, so I am looking for support in increasing its speed!

The code is as follows:

```
public BufferedImage getScreenPortion(Point topleft,Point bottomright){

    int width = bottomright.x - topleft.x;
    int height = bottomright.y - topleft.y;
    BufferedImage bi = new BufferedImage(width,height,BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);

    for(int p=0;p<height;p++){

    for(int i= 0;i<width;i++){

        Color pixel = robot.getPixelColor(topleft.x+i, topleft.y+p);
        bi.setRGB(i, p, pixel.getRGB());
        }
    }

    return bi;


}
```

and I am passing it :  `getScreenPortion(new Point(1081,824),new Point(1111,844));` which means I am trying to get an areas approximately 30x20 - yet it is taking in the region of 7 seconds which is horrendously slow!

Comment: Is there a reason this was tagged 'oracle'?

Comment: Fixed it - I now instead use:

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fixed it - I now instead use:

```
Rectangle screenRect = new Rectangle(topleft.x, topleft.y, width, height);
BufferedImage grid = robot.createScreenCapture(screenRect);
```

Comment: To create a code block, indent by four spaces.  Do not use [code][/code].

Comment: +1 Some related examples may be found [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3742731/java-how-to-draw-constantly-changing-graphics).