# setBackground(new color()); in java does not understand the given RGB value

Tags: java, swing, hex, rgb, setbackground

I have a program with some gui, on the JFrame I set,

```
 setBackground( new Color(107, 106, 104) );
```

The issue is that I get a greyish color, but not the right one. If I check it in PhotoShop, it gives me the RGB values (126, 125, 123)

Ps. I have tried with HEX value, the same result.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: I'd expect that color to be grey because the RGB values are so close. Colors between 0,0,0 (black) and 255,255,255 (white) are "grey" as long as each value is "similar"

Comment: Could it be because java uses sRGB instead of RGB? :P

Comment: [Bugreport](http://bugs.sun.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=6384420) on official bugtracker. And it is really not a bug.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
I have a program with some gui, on the JFrame I set,

 setBackground( new Color(107, 106, 104) );

[The problem] It gives a greyish color, but not the right one! 
If I check the gui's color in Photo Shop, it gives me the RGB 
values (126, 125, 123)
```

you can not set `setBackground` for `JFrame`, this is only possible for `ContentPane`, for example

```
JFrame#getContentPane.setBackground(new Color(107, 106, 104));
```

EDIT

[image]

from code

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class Check extends JFrame {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public void makeUI() {
        JFrame f = new JFrame();
        f.getContentPane().setBackground(new Color(107, 106, 104));
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.setSize(new Dimension(300, 200));
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                new Check().makeUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: It is in the constructor of a class that extends JFrame?

Comment: mKorbel, I have tested your code, it works like a charm. But the way i'am doing it, it won't work and I can't see why.

Comment: @JW_ this is reason why we asking for [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), nobody knows what ... :-)

Comment: @mKorbel's result verified using [`Zoom`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3742841/230513). I suspect an errant composite mode.

Comment: It's the right answer that getContentPane() needs to be called on the setBackground()

Answer (score 1):

check with Adam's comment and even if not worked then without any working code I am just guessing that this scenario is getting raised due zero ordering or saying layout of the JFrame.
Actually in java swing , setting the background color needs a little bit of more attention, check Swing Java Docs.

Answer (score 0):

i've tried what you explained; in awt it's no problem; in swing it seems the background is not set properly
did you check, if your background changes, e.g. with setBackground(Color.red)?

example Code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Tmp extends Frame { public static void main(String[] args) {
    //Frame tmp = new Frame();
    Frame tmp = new JFrame();
    tmp.setBackground(new Color(107, 106, 104));
    tmp.setSize(40,40);
    tmp.setVisible(true);
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

http://www.tayloredmktg.com/rgb/

It looks like gray is at the top of the page riht when you open it. :)
Also make sure your JFrame is opaque or you won't see your color!

```
setOpaque(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

***This worked for me.
Hope it helps***
*The, code, adds a JPanel, to current JFrame, you can further build guis on this panel. You can customize the RGB colours, on JPanel, not on JFrame.*

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Main{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        //Class class = new Class();
        frame.setSize(1920,1080);
        //frame.setTitle("XYZ");
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(panel);
        panel.setBackground(new Color(51,153,255));
        //panel.add(class);
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't post code only, add an explanation so that readers can better understand your answer

Answer (score 0):

First step - make an object of `jFrame`:

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
```

Second step:

```
frame.getContentPane().setBackground(new Color(16,144,144));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 if(evt.getSource() == jMenuItem11){
        getContentPane().setBackground(new Color(170, 8, 54));
    }
    if(evt.getSource() == jMenuItem12){
        getContentPane().setBackground(new Color(8, 54, 169));
    }
    if(evt.getSource() == jMenuItem13){
       getContentPane().setBackground(new Color(84, 8, 170));
    }
```

}

Comment: Please con't post code-only answers.  You need to explain what your code does/how it fixes the problem. Even if you think it's good enough for this one question, the site requires keeping a certain minimal standard of commentary, and there are reasons for it.