# How is it possible to get the coordinates of a Swing components, irrespective to its parent?

Tags: java, swing, components, coordinates

I am trying to get the coordinates of a component, for example a label. I tried getBounds, and getLocation, however they do not give accurate coordinates if the label is on 2 or more panels. Besides getLocationOnScreen, is there a way to be able to get accurate components' coordinates, even though they are on more than 1 panel?

Comment: How can a label be on more than one panel?

Comment: what I mean is, you have more than one panel layered on each other, each containing their components, and the label is not directly on the primary panel

Comment: Ah, you mean in more than one (nested) `Container`. What's wrong with `getLocationOnScreen()`?

Comment: yes your right sorry, for some reason it is still not giving me accurate location, especially when I maximize the frame

Comment: the x and y coordinate returned are being 8 and 29 units respectively  more then they actually are, so I have to stay decreasing these values. When I maximize the windows, the difference would be bigger

Comment: I am unable to reproduce this. It may help to edit your question to include an [sscce](http://sscce.org/) that exhibits the problem you describe.

Comment: *"I am trying to get the coordinates of a component,.."* Why exactly?  What program feature does that support?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want it relative to a JFrame, then you'll have to do something like this:

```
public static Point getPositionRelativeTo(Component root, Component comp) {
    if (comp.equals(root)) { return new Point(0,0); }
    Point pos = comp.getLocation();
    Point parentOff = getPositionRelativeTo(root, comp.getParent());
    return new Point(pos.x + parentOff.x, pos.y + parentOff.y);
}
```

Or you can just use the built-in solution `SwingUtilities.convertPoint(comp, 0, 0, root)`.

Comment: I can't argue with _that_! :-) Edit, well wanting this should make one question the need.

Answer (score 3):

Try Component.[getLocationOnScreen()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#getLocationOnScreen%28%29)

As the Javadoc says,

> Gets the location of this component in the form of a point specifying the component's top-left corner in the screen's coordinate space.

Comment: @AndrewThompson Thank you :) It took me almost a month for the last 100 reps! #LazyTheseDays :D

Comment: No stress, we all give what time we can.  No obligations (& no regrets).

Comment: @AndrewThompson Thats it! :) and I'm waiting to wish you on the 50K milestone :)

Answer (score 3):

As an alternative to [`getLocationOnScreen()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#getLocationOnScreen%28%29), you may be able to use [`getXOnScreen()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseEvent.html#getXOnScreen%28%29) and [`getYOnScreen()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseEvent.html#getYOnScreen%28%29) from a `MouseEvent`. [`Zoom`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3742841/230513) is an example.