# SunToolkit.awtLock: does code that takes such a lock needs to be called on the EDT

Tags: java, swing, awt

I was investigating a deadlock and saw the following in the thread dump

```
at sun.awt.SunToolkit.awtLock(SunToolkit.java:229)
at sun.awt.X11.XRobotPeer.setup(Native Method)
- locked <0x00000000a633fbd0> (a java.lang.Class for sun.awt.X11.XRobotPeer)
at sun.awt.X11.XRobotPeer.<init>(XRobotPeer.java:24)
at sun.awt.X11.XToolkit.createRobot(XToolkit.java:683)
at java.awt.Robot.init(Robot.java:119)
at java.awt.Robot.<init>(Robot.java:77)
```

This is caused by calling `Robot robot = new Robot();`

This call takes a lock (`SunToolkit.awtLock`) and I was wondering who else is using that lock, and if it would be better if I moved that `new Robot()` call to the EDT. The name suggests that it is used by AWT which is single threaded. If something on the EDT takes this lock as well (e.g. a Swing component), my chances of hitting a deadlock increase when I create the `Robot` off the EDT.

On the other hand, as discussed in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10468432/1076463), a lot of the `Robot` methods are designed to throw an exception when called on the EDT. This would make it annoying if you would be best to create the `Robot` instance on the EDT.

The same problem exists for `Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenResolution()` so no need to focus solely on the `Robot` class:

```
at sun.awt.SunToolkit.awtLock(SunToolkit.java:229)
at sun.awt.X11.XToolkit.getScreenResolution(XToolkit.java:999)
```

So what I am trying to clear up:

- Who are the interested parties in that lock ?
- Was that lock perhaps only introduced in an attempt to make Swing/AWT multi-threaded (or at least a bit more thread-safe), but would the recommended approach be to avoid taking that lock on another thread then the EDT ?
- Is there any official Oracle/Sun documentation available (something like the Concurrency in Swing guide) which I can consult ? My Google skills failed me on this.

Comment: [EDT and awt.Robot???, then please to see question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10468432/do-robot-methods-need-to-be-run-on-the-event-queue) by @Hovercraft Full Of Eels

Comment: What is the other deadlock stack?

Comment: @GuillaumePolet The stack was weird. There were threads waiting for a lock but nobody hold the lock. We assume that it was caused by JOGL who apparently exposes that `awtLock` and uses it. But the deadlock is fixed in the mean time. I was just wondering what that awtLock does, as stated in the question

Comment: I always _assumed_ it was shared with the JNI code that manipulates the host platform's peer component, but I've never looked that far under the hood.

Answer (score 1):

See the source code for SunToolkit.java here: http://www.docjar.com/html/api/sun/awt/SunToolkit.java.html 
the purpose of the AWT_LOCK is explained on line 208.

Here's the excerpt in case the page disappears:

> ```
> /** 
>  * The AWT lock is typically only used on Unix platforms to synchronize
>  * access to Xlib, OpenGL, etc.  However, these methods are implemented
>  * in SunToolkit so that they can be called from shared code (e.g.
>  * from the OGL pipeline) or from the X11 pipeline regardless of whether
>  * XToolkit or MToolkit is currently in use.  There are native macros
>  * (such as AWT_LOCK) defined in awt.h, so if the implementation of these
>  * methods is changed, make sure it is compatible with the native macros.
>  *   
>  * Note: The following methods (awtLock(), awtUnlock(), etc) should be
>  * used in place of: 
>  *     synchronized (getAWTLock()) {
>  *         ... 
>  *     }   
>  *   
>  * By factoring these methods out specially, we are able to change the 
>  * implementation of these methods (e.g. use more advanced locking
>  * mechanisms) without impacting calling code.
>  *   
>  * Sample usage:
>  *     private void doStuffWithXlib() {
>  *         assert !SunToolkit.isAWTLockHeldByCurrentThread();
>  *         SunToolkit.awtLock();
>  *         try {
>  *             ... 
>  *             XlibWrapper.XDoStuff();
>  *         } finally {
>  *             SunToolkit.awtUnlock();
>  *         }   
>  *     }   
>  */
> ```