# How to set " very dark blue " background color to the JButton?

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, uicolor

I am trying to create a simple button which should look like  this-

[image]

```
JButton connectBtn = new JButton("Connect");
        Color blue = new Color(77,176,230);    
        connectBtn.setBackground(blue);
```

But the problem is the background blue color is not as dark as it should look.

I have tried all the below possibilities,but of no use:-(

```
connectBtn.setBackground(Color.blue);

connectBtn.setBackground(Color.BLUE.brighter());

connectBtn.setBackground(Color.decode("#0099cc"));//i tried simply #0099cc just to get any dark background
```

Kindly help me in setting this color to JButton background.
Thanks.

Comment: Printscreen -> Paint -> Colorpicker tells me that the color of the button is `1691d9` (or `22,145,217`), if that helps.

Comment: @Keppil AFAIU - that is effectively 'the answer', though I disagree with the OP that it is a 'very dark blue' in the image.

Answer (score 2):

PrintScreen -> Paint -> Colorpicker tells me that the color of your button is

```
1691D9
```

or

```
(22,145,217)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.Actually I already tried the same RGB value .But it looks lighter. But same color if I set it to the text on the Connect button,it looks darker.Not only this any color which looks darker on paint doesn;t look same on JButton:-(

Answer (score 2):

[`Zoom`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3742841/230513) shows that your button is painted with a gradient that includes several shades of blue, as well as anti-aliased text. You'll probably need a suitable `ButtonUI`, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5755124/230513) using `GradientPaint`. Note the use of `RenderingHints` to suggest aliasing settings.