# Trying to retrieve the color from a grid at location x,y JPANEL

Tags: java, swing

So in my class that extends JPanel I have:

```
`class Pane extends JPanel {
public static final int MAX_X = 10; //Width
public static final int MAX_Y = MAX_X; //Height
private static final int CELL_WIDTH = 50; 
private static final int PREF_W = CELL_WIDTH * MAX_X;
private static final int PREF_H = CELL_WIDTH * MAX_Y;
private static final Color FILL_COLOR = Color.red;
static final Color GEM_COLOR = Color.blue;
```

}`

```
@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
   g.setColor(FILL_COLOR);
   g.fillRect(x * CELL_WIDTH, y * CELL_WIDTH, CELL_WIDTH, CELL_WIDTH);
 }
```

What I want to do is outside of this class at location x and y, retrieve the color while traversing through the panel.
Help would be much appreciated, Thank you!

Comment: Make it not private, then use `Pane.FILL_COLOR`?

Comment: Well I know how to retrieve the color from FiILL_COLOR. What I want to do is retrieve the color that has been filled on the grid. For instance at location (2,1)

Comment: Oh and im actually looking for GEM_COLOR which is why that is not private

Comment: If you're looking for GEM_COLOR then use `Pane.GEM_COLOR`?

Comment: Sorry I didnt meant to confuse anyone, I know how to find Gem_COLOR, I want to compare that GEM_COLOR with ever place in the grid until it matches the color

Comment: What grid? I see no grid. Is there one Pane per grid cell?

Comment: Yes i didnt put the grid code on here because its long and not needed for the question. is there a built in function similar to  Pane.getComponentAt(x, y).getColorModel()

Comment: So you're asking a question about code you haven't posted. How do you expect anyone to answer it without seeing the code it's about?

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Answer (score 0):

Options:

1. [How to get the color of a point in a JPanel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13307962/how-to-get-the-color-of-a-point-in-a-jpanel)
2. createScreenCapture() with Robot and search for the pixel
3. Use a 2d array to keep track of all the drawn colors on JPanel