# using Affine Transformation to draw UTM Coordinates in JPEG file

Tags: java

How can i transform UTM Coordinates into pixels using JAVA 2D API,then draw them in JPEG file?

Answer (score 0):

Jerry Huxtable's delightful [Globe Applet](http://www.jhlabs.com/java/maps/proj/index.html) supports Universal Transverse Mercator (UTM) coordinate transformations. [`ImageIO`](http://www.jhlabs.com/java/maps/proj/index.html) provides simple methods to write in JPEG format.

Addendum: The [Globe Applet](http://www.jhlabs.com/java/maps/proj/index.html) is based on the [*Java Map Projection Library*](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jmapprojlib/), which includes [`MercatorProjection`](http://jmapprojlib.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/jmapprojlib/JMapProjLib/src/com/jhlabs/map/proj/MercatorProjection.java). The article [*Map Projection*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Map_projection) offers an overview of the topic with several useful references. If simple linear interpolation is sufficient, this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2901472) may suggest an approach.

Comment: Can someone help me with a code sample because that is a lot easier to follow and understand.i would like a simple way of doing this in java.