# how to show pixel array of an image in python or java??? help me

Tags: java, python

I am new in python n java. I've given the task at my class for showing pixel array image from an image. Please help me??
Thanks

Comment: I mean the RGB value each pixel of an image.

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to get a 2D array if each pixel color? In the Java BufferedImage class, there is the method:

```
getRGB(int x, int y)
```

Therefore, you could just loop through each pixel and add it to your array, like this:

```
int[][] array = new int[img.getWidth()][img.getHeight()];
for (int i = 0; i < img.getWidth(); i++) {
   for (int j = 0; i < img.getHeight(); j++) {
      array[i][j] = img.getRGB(i, j);
   }
}
```

This will give you a 2D array of the RGB value of each pixel.

Comment: Thanks very much. it's really I am need for doing my homework.. :D

Answer (score 0):

You might study this Java [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2901472) that uses the graphics context's `drawImage()` to enlarge an image and report the color of each pixel.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look in to the Python Image Library [(PIL)](http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/), I recommend it.

Comment: where can i download PIL for python 3? I never found it

Comment: I don't think they support it yet