# Overlay images on a GridLayout in Java

Tags: java, image, swing, grid-layout

Is it possible to have one set of images be the "background image" of a gridlayout and other images be the "content" of the gridlayout?

If not, what's the best way to do it?

Comment: Hovercraft is right. To add an image inside a cell of the GridLayout, you may add new JLabel(null, image)

Comment: please see edit to post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is it possible to have the background image resize with the rest?

Yes, `drawImage()` can scale to the full size of the container, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2900801/wanting-a-type-of-grid-for-a-pixel-editor/2901472#2901472).

> Is it possible to set the background image of each *cell*?

Yes, `getSubimage()` is helpful in this context, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3078178/jpanel-in-puzzle-game-not-updating/3078354#3078354).

Answer (score 6):

Yes it's certainly possible. Make one the background of the JPanel that holds the GridLayout. This can be done by drawing the image in the JPanel's paintComponent method.  If you want the cells of the grid to show the background image though, be sure to set their opaque property false. If they're JLabels this is already done by default though.

Edit: For example:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class OverLayImages extends JPanel {
   public static final String BACKGROUND_URL = "http://duke.kenai.com/misc/Bullfight.jpg";
   public static final String CELL_URL = "http://duke.kenai.com/iconSized/penduke-transparent.gif";
   private static final int ROWS = 3;
   private static final int COLS = 4;
   private BufferedImage backgroundImage;
   private BufferedImage cellImage;

   public OverLayImages() throws MalformedURLException, IOException {
      backgroundImage = ImageIO.read(new URL(BACKGROUND_URL));
      cellImage = ImageIO.read(new URL(CELL_URL));
      ImageIcon cellIcon = new ImageIcon(cellImage);
      setBackground(Color.white);

      setPreferredSize(new Dimension(backgroundImage.getWidth(), backgroundImage.getHeight()));

      setLayout(new GridLayout(ROWS, COLS));
      for (int i = 0; i < ROWS; i++) {
         for (int j = 0; j < COLS; j++) {
            JLabel label = new JLabel(cellIcon);
            add(label);
         }
      }
   }

   @Override
   protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
      super.paintComponent(g);
      if (backgroundImage != null) {
         g.drawImage(backgroundImage, 0, 0, null);
      }
   }

   private static void createAndShowUI() {
      JFrame frame = new JFrame("OverLayImages");
      try {
         frame.getContentPane().add(new OverLayImages());
      } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
         System.exit(1);
      } catch (IOException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
         System.exit(1);
      }
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.pack();
      frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            createAndShowUI();
         }
      });
   }
}
```

Comment: You can also tinker with the `hgap` and `vgap`.

Comment: Is it possible to have the background image resize with the rest?
OR Is it possible to set the background image of each CELL?

Comment: @Johannes: Yes and yes; I've elaborated in an adjacent answer.