# Converting a ImageIcon array to a BufferedImage

Tags: java, arrays, bufferedimage, imageicon

I was wondering if there was a way of having a ImageIcon[] converted into a series of Buffered Image, I was thinking along the lines of something like this:

```
  public BufferedImage iconArrayToBufferedImage(ImageIcon[] icon){
    for (int i = 0; i < icon.length; i++) {
        BufferedImage screenShot = new BufferedImage(icon[i]);
    }


    return screenShot;

}
```

Comment: Is your goal to layout the icons horizontally, vertically, or in a 2D layout?  Or is your goal to create an array of buffered images, with one for each image icon?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

E.G. as seen in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6368724/418556).

```
BufferedImage bi = new BufferedImage(
    icon.getIconWidth(),
    icon.getIconHeight(),
    BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
Graphics g = bi.createGraphics();
// paint the Icon to the BufferedImage.
icon.paintIcon(null, g, 0,0);
g.dispose();
```

For many icons, do that in a loop.

Comment: That works, but would there be a way to concatenate the multiple images together, into a single BufferedImage?

Comment: Sure, it only takes a little logic (make final image bigger, loop the small images) and painting the image parts at the right places (look at the arguments for `paintIcon`).