# Using Graphics outside the paintComponent

Tags: java, swing, graphics, paintcomponent

Let's say we have the following situation:

```
JPanel panelp=new JPanel();
paintSomething(panelp.getGraphics();
```

and somewhere else in a different object, the method:

```
void paintSomething(Graphics g){ /*code*/ }
```

I don't want to override `paintComponent` method of `panelp`.  How can I paint something to `panelp` from the method `paintSomething` using the `Graphics` of `panelp`?

Comment: Why don't you want to override `paintComponent`? It's the recommended way to do custom painting in Swing.

Comment: Are there any components in `panelp`?

Comment: yes it has many components. I want to make some animations between those components.

Answer (score 4):

`whatever.getGraphics()` is snapshot is the snapshot that will go away when

- after first repaint
- `JComponets` are repainted internally from `Mouse` or `Key Events`, these events are implemented in the concrete `JComponets API`
- simple example for usage of `whatever.getGraphics()` is printing to the printer or saving current GUI as printscreen to the e.g. JPEG or PGN File

basic stuff is described in the [2D Graphics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/index.html)

Comment: +1 You just resolved a question that I had in the back of my head!

Comment: Oh so is there a method to draw something to a component from outside?

Comment: @ClaudiuC: Use a `BufferedImage`, for [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2901472/230513).

Comment: if you maning from another class, method or void then basically yes no idea what wrong with that, you can put arrays of Object to the paintComponent delayed with Swing Timer,

Answer (score 3):

You could draw your stuff in the `paintSomething` into a `BufferedImage` which you can then draw to the panel by overriding `paintComponent`

Comment: I can't. I want to create some animations over the panel like microsoft word's Clippy