# Draw image using rectangles

Tags: java, image, swing

I wrote a program that reads an image from command line and want to read each pixel to draw a rectangle of the respective colour to "recreate" the image from rectangles.

However, although the rectangles have the correct size, every pixel seems to be black. At least, what I see in the output panel is a black picture that has the same size as the input picture.

```
    class AppDrawPanel extends JPanel {  

        private BufferedImage bi;

        /* ... */

        public void loadAPPImage( String s ) throws IOException{
             bi = ImageIO.read(new File(s));
        }

        @Override
        public void paint(Graphics g){
           Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
           int w = bi.getWidth();
           int h = bi.getHeight();

           for( int x = 0; x < w; x++){
                for ( int z = 0; z < h; z++ ){
                        Color c = new Color(bi.getRGB(x, z));
                        super.setForeground(c);
                        g2.fillRect(x, z, 3, 3);  
                }    
           }
        }
    }
```

And the main function:

```
    public static void main( String[] args ) throws IOException{         
        /* ... */

        AppDrawPanel draw = new AppDrawPanel();
        draw.loadAPPImage(args[0]);
        frame.add(draw);        
        /* ... */
    }
```

where `/* ... */` represents code that has nothing to do with drawing the rectangles or reading the image.

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete and Verifiable Example). 2) One way to get image(s) for an example is to hot-link to the images seen in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19209651/418556). 3) Given this is a Q&A site, it's best to from an explicit question like 'How to draw the boxes so they aren't black?' or 'What is the error?'.  What is your question?

Comment: The `super.setForeground(c);` should probably simply be `g2.setColor(c)`.

Comment: @Marco13 thank you, it works :) @ Andrew Thompson Thank you for your advices :)

Comment: Nevertheless, have a look at the answer from trashgod. Simply painting the image *larger* is **much** more efficient than painting thousands of rectangles. (Although, based on the question, one has to consider the possibility that you chose your approach intentionally...)

Comment: @Marco13 yes, it's a homework and I had to do it with rectangles, because we had to implement different black/white-functions ;)

Comment: The scale functions in `mouseMoved()` will also work for hit testing in `mouseClicked()`.

Answer (score 3):

In this related [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2901472/230513), the width and height of each pixel is scaled by an arbitrary factor of 10. The method `drawImage()` then scales the image to the component's preferred size. As an exercise, override [`getPreferredSize()`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7229226/230513) to return an appropriate dimension:

```
new Dimension(imgW * 10, imgH * 10);
```

Also consider making the arbitrary factor a class-level property.