# Scaling a Pixel Array in Java

Tags: java, arrays, graphics, scale, pixel

I have been messing around with re-sizing arrays of pixels. I have managed to make some code that scales up the pixels when they are rendered. The problem with the code is that I can only scale the pixels up with whole numbers (1, 2, 3, etc.). I want to be able to scale the pixels up using a double (.001, .002, etc) so I am not restrained to only a few image sizes.
Here is the code I wrote:

```
public void draw(Sprite s, int xCord, int yCord, int scale){
    for(int y = 0; y < s.getHeight()*scale; y++){
        for(int x = 0; x <s.getWidth()*scale; x++){
            pixels[(x+xCord) +(y+yCord)*this.width]
                = s.pixels[(x/scale+ y/scale * s.getWidth())];
        }       
    }
}
```

Can this be easily tweaked to allow for non-whole number scales?

The class Sprite knows its own width and height given by `s.getWidth()` and `s.getHeight()`.
The height and width are the actual dimensions in pixels of the .png when it was read.

Comment: Not very easily, no, and you're going to end up with blurry results. If you want to go ahead anyway, think about it as having a grid of colors superimposing a finer grid, and looking at the results of that finer grid. You will have to take a weighted average of 2 or 4 pixels for at least some of the pixels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For flexibility in choosing the [resampling algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_scaling), use `AffineTransformOp`, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4216635/230513), or just let the graphics context handle it, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2901472/230513).